# Excel VBA - Make fields required but save blank fields

Tags: excel, vba

I have added the following code to make fields required before saving them.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(2, 2).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter Date"
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

However, our requirement is that the fields should be blank when the excel file is openEd by the user. My problem is that the code does not allow me to save the file for the first time with blank fields.

Can you please suggest a workaround? I'm not happy that MS Excel does not a required field option...

Comment: You could disable macros, save the workbook, then re-enable macros again.

Comment: You could add a condition that username<>your_username as well?

Comment: Or invent a sentinel value, and if that value is found in `Cells(2,2)` replace it with the empty string?

Comment: Thanks BenShelton, CallumDA and AlexP for your quick replies! Really appreciate it. I disabled macros using the 'pause' button and saved the workbook. That worked great. Thanks again!

Comment: You cou disable events by  Application.EnableEvents = False and then save the workbook and re-enable Events again

Comment: If it is always the current date you can simply put it in for the user with if cells(2,2) = "" then cells(2,2) = format(date, "mm/dd/yy").

Comment: Storax - I tried that but if I reenable events again, I'm not able to save the workbook.

Comment: John -Thanks. It is not only the current date. There are many other fields.